# Conditional Formatting with Office 2008 for Mac

Tags: mac, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I'm working with a 2,000 line spreadsheet in which I want to isolate certain lines based upon certain key words in descriptions contained in the 1st column.  I have tried using Conditional Formatting /  Formula Is / "xxxx" to no avail. Not sure what I am doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Are you matching the whole cell contents? If so, assuming data in column A then use a formula like

`=$A1="xxxx"`

or for partial matches

`=SEARCH("xxxx",$A1)`